# Is there a way to parse JSON in a **coffeescript** way?

Tags: json, parsing, coffeescript

I know in Jquery, we parse using $.parseJSON(). I would like to know, if there is a alternative to that in Coffeescript?

Comment: Modern browsers provide `JSON.parse()` as part of Javascript. jQuery wraps that and provides an alternative for browsers that don't have it. You should be able to use it directly in CffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there isn't. The JSON parsing that happens with coffeescript happens when the coffee files are compiled into JS files, and you would have to eval the JSON, which is **very bad** practice.

Comment: oh thanks for the quick response. I was just curious, if at all there is a way.